# Usar setter para imprimir información esta mal?

Tags: java

Según entiendo, los setter son aquellos métodos que no retornar valor, por eso se utiliza **void** al declarar un setter, con el fin de fijar el valor de un atributo, en mi caso, utilice este setter para construir un programa que me proporciona una bola de bingo sin repetir, pero en el mismo setter imprimo por pantalla dicha bola que calcula el setter y no se si eso es correcto, en teoría es valido porque no da ningún error, pero me gustaría saber si es conveniente o convencional hacer esto.

```
public void mostrar_bola(){

    number = (int)(Math.random()*75+1);
    if(bingo[number - 1] != 0){
        System.out.println("La bola escogida es: " + bingo[number-1]+ " " + 
        set_letras(number)); 
    }else{
        while (bingo[number - 1] == 0) {                
            number = (int)(Math.random()*75+1);
        }
        System.out.println("La bola escogida es: " + bingo[number-1]+ " " + 
        set_letras(number));              
    }
    bingo[number - 1] = 0;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta correcto, no hay ningun problema.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es crear esta clase lo más bonita possible puedes hacer el metodo "setNuevaBola" <- que añada la ultima bola al array de bolas sacadas hasta el momento, con la lógica que quieras.

Y luego crear otro método llamado algo como "muestraUltimaBola"

Así el ciclo de uso de la classe bingo en la función main() sería:

```
bingo.setNuevaBola()
System.out.println(bingo.muestraUltimaBola)
```

Lo que no entiendo es set_letras(). Si muestras la classe entera quizás se puede perfeccionar.

Otra cosa mejorable es que repites codigo y esto es una de las "màximas" a evitar, siempre.

Luego, a ver que te parece simplificar el código para sacar un número nuevo cada vez, algo así:

```
    // Crea el "bombo" con todos los números
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Creamos un 
    ArrayList de Integers
    int miBingoMax = 75;
    for (int i = 0; i < miBingoMax; i++) {
        numeros.add(i + 1);
    }

    // Ahora ya tenemos el "bombo" numeros con todos los numeros
    // En el metodo "sacarBola" hacemos: 
    int indexSacamos = (int) (Math.random() * (numeros.size() - 1));        
    int numeroSalido =  numeros.get(indexSacamos);
    numeros.remove(indexSacamos);
    
    // numeroSalido tiene el numero que ha tocado este turno
    // Como lo sacamos del array ya nunca mas podra volver a salir.        
    
    System.out.println(numeroSalido);
```

Solo faltaría, quizas, guardar en un array las bolas que ya han salido (para mostrarlas si se necesita), y mostrar por pantalla la bola que ha tocado, en metodos separados

```
guardarNumero(numeroSalido) // crear este metodo
mostrarBola(numeroSalido) // crear este metodo con un print i au.
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias en serio!!! me haz enseñado un monton!